# Define identifiers in foreign languages

Tags: unicode, ocaml, lexer

At the moment, in my `tokens.mll`, I have defined the following tokens to build `latin_identifier`.

```
let decimal_digit = ['0'-'9']
let first_latin_identifier_character = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']
let subsequent_latin_identifier_character = first_latin_identifier_character | '\x5F' (* underscore *) | decimal_digit
let latin_identifier = first_latin_identifier_character subsequent_latin_identifier_character*
```

However, this setting does not cover identifiers like `ZÄHLENWENNS`, `SENÃODISP`, `TipoDeAusência_Férias`.

Does anyone know how to make identifiers cover spanish, french, german, and even chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to switch to sedlex https://github.com/ocaml-community/sedlex
which has built-in support for unicode classes of codepoints (in particular `id_start` and `id_continue`).